# JavaScript not working after making changes

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a java script that basically changes the zindex of an image when mouse is over it. although this works i have had to redo some of the dimentions and positioning in the CSS. now the scrip is not running for the images. to see an example go to http://officialacescottie.co.uk and check Home for not working and any other for it working.

**JS**

```
<script>

A=""
function mouseover1() {
document.getElementById(A).style.zIndex="1"
}
function mouseoff1() {
document.getElementById(A).style.zIndex="100"
}
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#HButton { background-image:url(../DefaultPage/Buttons/Home.gif); background-color:#000; height:14.8%; width:100%; color:#FFF; background-size:100%; position:absolute; z-index:90; left:0px; background-repeat:no-repeat;}

#HButton2 { background-image: url(../DefaultPage/Buttons/HomeP.gif); background-color:#000; height:14.8%; width:100%; color:#FFF; background-size:100%; position:absolute; z-index:89; top:0px; left:0px; background-repeat:no-repeat;}
```

That's the CSS code that is broken

---

This one works:

**CSS**

```
#HButton { background-image:url(../DefaultPage/Buttons/Home.gif); background-color:#000; float:left; height:60px; width:350px; color:#FFF; background-size:100%; position:relative; z-index:90;}

#HButton2 { background-image: url(../DefaultPage/Buttons/HomeP.gif); background-color:#000; float:left; height:60px; width:350px; color:#FFF; background-size:100%; position:relative; z-index:10; top:-60px;}
```

Both codes use same div tag

**HTML**

```
<div id="HButton" onmouseover="A='HButton'; mouseover1()" onmouseout="A='HButton'; mouseoff1()">
</div>
<div id="HButton2" onmouseover="A='HButton'; mouseover1()" onmouseout="A='HButton'; mouseoff1()">
</div>
```

Comment: As I see on your webpage none of them is working, cause you didn't close your script tag. But that's the least of your problems.

Comment: You can't use HTML comment tags inside script tag. Remove this comments and put your script with functions at head section and that's all.

Comment: thanks. i was using Adobe templates so i did not notice. The template did not update the rest annoyingly. lesson learned, don't use templates. if you want to point out my main problem id appreciate it. only been doing this about 3 days so still a noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 differences that I was able to spot:

```
1)  You have google ads on home but not AceWorks (dont think this is causing the issue)
2)  You closed the script tag on AceWorks but missed it on Home
```

Please adjust #2.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot semicolons?
A="";
Its important in javascript
But best solutiin is passing variable A in function

function mouseover1(A)

Comment: Its inside the html so no separate JS file and it works as is just not with the Home page. every other page which i haven't edited still works, same exact code apart from the CSS. I was told you don't put ; in the html.

Answer (score 0):

Check your console log it is saying the functions are not defined.

Also another approach could be this:

**Javascript**

```
function mouseIn(y){
    y.style.zIndex = "1";
}

function mouseOut(y){
    y.style.zIndex = "100";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="HButton" onmouseover="mouseIn(this)" onmouseout="mouseOut(this)"></div>
```